# adjustbox for 'Overfull \hbox LaTeX' with subfloat and minipage

Tags: floats, subfloats, minipage, adjustbox

I am trying to put two figures (separately stored in two .pdf files) vertically in a one-column style. `\subfigure` is not allowed, and below is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \subfloat[1]{
        \begin{minipage}[t]{1\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width = 1\linewidth]{1.pdf}
        \end{minipage}
        \label{1}
    }
    \\
    \subfloat[2]{
        \begin{minipage}[t]{1\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width = 1\linewidth]{2.pdf}
        \end{minipage}
        \label{2}
    }
    \caption{0}
    \label{0}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

However, I got the warning of `Overfull \hbox (10.77068pt too wide)LaTeX`. I searched and found the `\adjustbox` can solve it with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=\linewidth}
    \subfloat[1]{
        \begin{minipage}[t]{1\linewidth}        
            \includegraphics[width = 1\linewidth]{1.pdf}
        \end{minipage}
        \label{1}
    }
    \end{adjustbox}
    \\
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=\linewidth}
    \subfloat[2]{
        \begin{minipage}[t]{1\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width = 1\linewidth]{2.pdf}
        \end{minipage}
        \label{2}
    }
    \end{adjustbox}
    \caption{0}
    \label{0}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But I thought it kind of sophisticated to duplicate the adjustbox, and tried with this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \adjustbox{width=\linewidth}{
    \subfloat[1]{
        \begin{minipage}[t]{1\linewidth}        
            \includegraphics[width = 1\linewidth]{1.pdf}
        \end{minipage}
        \label{1}
    }
    \\
    \subfloat[2]{
        \begin{minipage}[t]{1\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width = 1\linewidth]{2.pdf}
        \end{minipage}
        \label{2}
    }
    }
    \caption{0}
    \label{0}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

to set the whole figure at one time, but got the error of `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` in the `\\` in front of `\subfloat[2]{`

[image]

So is there anyway to solve the problem easily?

Comment: Welcome to TexSE :) // Your question is clear. However, I'd like to ask you to ad the preamble and the `\begin{document} .. \end{document}` statements. On one hand it makes clear, which packages you use or did not, but should, use. On the other hand we simply can copy and run your code. Thanks

Comment: @MS-SPO, thanks for your reminder, and I have added them as required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eliminate the Overfull  by inserting `%` after `\subfloat`, `\label` and  `\end{minipage}` to eliminate the extra spaces.

(Updated after  @David Carlisle comment)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{showframe} % ONLY to show the margins <<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{graphicx} % to add example-image


\begin{document}

Some text.

\begin{figure}[H]       
    \centering
    \subfloat[1]{% <<<<<<<<<<<<
    \begin{minipage}[t]{1\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width = 1\linewidth,height=150pt]{example-image}
          \end{minipage}%<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \label{1}% <<<<<<<<<<<<
    }
    \\
    \subfloat[2]{% <<<<<<<<<<<<
    \begin{minipage}[t]{1\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width = 1\linewidth,height=150pt]{example-image}
          \end{minipage}%<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \label{2}% <<<<<<<<<<<<
    }
    \caption{0}
    \label{0}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: a]

The simplest code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]       
    \centering
    \subfloat[1\label{1}]{% label here 
        \includegraphics[width = 1\linewidth,height=150pt]{example-image}%      
     }
    \\
    \subfloat[2]{%
        \includegraphics[width = 1\linewidth,height=150pt]{example-image}%
        \label{2}%   or label here
    }
    \caption{0}
    \label{0}
\end{figure
```

Comment: there is no difference beween minipage and `\parbox` here. You fixed the issue as you removed the spurious white space by adding `%`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, and Simon Dispa, thanks for your help. Adding the `%` did solve the problem. But why? Adding `%` seems to comment out the space before and after the figure?

Comment: @yangtzech `\fbox{ x }` is wider than `\fbox{x}` you were making a box wih an inner box ha was `\linewidth` wide, with a space before and after, so two spaces wider than you want.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Got it.